# How to check if input file is empty in jquery without using another button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect if an image has been selected. If so, then display some text otherwise if its empty display some other text. As soon as the image is selected, automatically different message should be shown not after clicking a button. The following is my code.

**Html**

```
<input type="file" name="picture" id="image" />
<div id="message">Add image</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(
 if ($('#image').get(0).files.length !== 0) {
  function() {
    $('#message').text('You added an image');
   }
 }
);
```

Comment: You can use select with predefined images and monitor with jQuery any change in selected item.

Comment: You execute your jQuery when the DOM loads so the file input won't ever have a length, nor will that code execute when the file input changes

Comment: This is very strangely structured.  It seems like you took the `function(){}` that should be there for the document ready, and moved it down into your if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a listener on the `input` and change the content of `message` as follows:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
     $('#image').on('change', function(){
          $('#message').html('You selected an image');
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="picture" id="image" />
<div id="message">Add image</div>
```